# Is it possible to get parameters of DBALException in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a constraint on one of my table, I would like to get one of the parameters when the exception `Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException` is thrown to customize the error message.

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="tile",
 *    uniqueConstraints={
 *        @UniqueConstraint(name="unique_image_tileset",
 *            columns={"tileset_id", "image"})
 *    })
```

In my controller, I have :

```
try {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    /** some logic **/
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        try {
            /* @var $file \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile */
            $tile = new Tile();
            $tile->setImageFile($file);
            $tileset->addTile($tile);
            $tiles[] = $tile;
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            $errors['warning'][] = $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
    /** some more logic **/
    $em->persist($tileset);
    $em->flush();
    /** some more logic **/
} catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $ex) {
    $errors['warning'][] = $this->_translator->trans('The image name %imagename% is already used for this tileset',array(),'exceptions');
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    $errors['warning'][] = $ex->getMessage();
}
```

There is a `formatParameters` function on `Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException` but it is private. Is there another way ?

Comment: It is always possible to get value of this parameter through `Reflection`

Comment: @Flying can you tell me more about Reflection ? Thanks

Comment: @ChristopheFerreboeuf Looks like my assumption was wrong. By looking into sources of `DBALException` ([1](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/b90d6324d3056ed89641efe0cfdfb9947b9148a3/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php#L155), [2](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/b90d6324d3056ed89641efe0cfdfb9947b9148a3/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php#L172)) it can be seen that original exception can be obtained by `$ex->getPrevious()` and, depending on its type it may provide parameters explicitly or it may require parsing error message text

Comment: @Flying, it is not possible to get it but thanks for your explaination. I can parse the string but it is faster (and maybe safier as well) to check before.

Comment: reason for proposal to parse string is, again, DBAL sources. [Take a look](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/b90d6324d3056ed89641efe0cfdfb9947b9148a3/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php#L51-L55) at how `UniqueConstraintViolationException` is generated (MySQL by my link. but other databases behaves in the same way). As you can see - this exception by itself is just a conversion of underlying exception that came from database driver. Hence the only information that is available inside is just message that came from SQL server.

Comment: Yes, I got it. I think it could be an improvement to be able to access the parameters as in `driverExceptionDuringQuery` when working with collections but I still consider myself as newbie on symfony and doctrine and I would not dare to propose.

Comment: It may be worth to submit a [feature request](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues) to Doctrine developers

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, it looks like it is not possible even with the help of getPrevious. I ended checking before adding tile to tileset.